# Error message when while generating a listview

Tags: android, error-handling

```
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657): java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    06-20 22:53:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(657):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-20 22:53:44.380: I/Process(657): Sending signal. PID: 657 SIG: 9
```

Can anybody please tell me what this error log says?

```
public class Timetablledisplay extends Activity {

ListView lv;
TextView tv;
TextView td;

Gallery myHorizontalListView1;
Gallery myHorizontalListView2;
Gallery myHorizontalListView3;
Gallery myHorizontalListView4;
Gallery myHorizontalListView5;
Gallery myHorizontalListView6;


static int position;
int datepos=0;
Button back,front; 

TextView e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6;

String p0[]={"Free","Free","Free","Free","Free","Free"};
String p01[]={"Free","Free","Free","Free","Free","Free"};
String p1[]=new String[40];
String p2[]=new String[40];
String p3[]=new String[40];
String p4[]=new String[40];
String p5[]=new String[40];
String p6[]=new String[40];

String sub[]=new String[40];
String sub1[]=new String[40];
String sub2[]=new String[40];
String sub3[]=new String[40];
String sub4[]=new String[40];
String sub5[]=new String[40];

String[] sw=new String[23];
String restoredText,restoredText1,restoredText2;


String x[]={"Attended","Bunked","Free Hour"};
String x1[]={"Attended","Bunked","Holiday"};


Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Date newDate1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timetabledisplay);
    try{
        getSettings();
        getTimeTablesetting();


        Log.d("ERRRRRORRR",""+p1[0]);

        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textdate);
        td=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textday);

        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
        newDate1 = c.getTime();

        td.setText(setdate(newDate1.getDay()));
        try{
            int i;
            //get it from database
            for(i=0;i<ProjectBunkitActivity.pos;i++){
                p1[i]=sub[i];
                p2[i]=sub1[i];
                p3[i]=sub2[i];
                p4[i]=sub3[i];
                p5[i]=sub4[i];
                p6[i]=sub5[i];
            }
            Log.d("ERRRRRORRR",""+p1[0]);
            dateUpdate();
            Log.d("DATEUPDATE", "HGJVVM");

            front=(Button)findViewById(R.id.fwdarrow);
            back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bckarrow);


            Log.d("DBBBBBBPOSITION5",""+position);


            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            Date newd=cal.getTime();
            Log.d("date",""+newd.getDay());
            try{
                if(setdate(newDate1.getDay())=="MON")
                {
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            R.layout.listarray, android.R.id.text1, p1);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                else if(setdate(newDate1.getDay())=="TUE"){

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            R.layout.listarray, android.R.id.text1, p2);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
                else if(setdate(newDate1.getDay())=="WED"){

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            R.layout.listarray, android.R.id.text1, p3);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
                else if(setdate(newDate1.getDay())=="THU"){

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            R.layout.listarray, android.R.id.text1, p4);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
                else if(setdate(newDate1.getDay())=="FRI"){

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            R.layout.listarray, android.R.id.text1, p5);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
                else if(setdate(newDate1.getDay())=="SAT"){

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            R.layout.listarray, android.R.id.text1, p6);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
                else 
                {

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            R.layout.listarray, android.R.id.text1, p1);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


                }



            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }




            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Timetablledisplay.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Pick a choice");
                    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(x, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), x[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if(newDate1.getDay()==1){
                                changeLabel(arg2, item, p1, 1);
                            }
                            else if(newDate1.getDay()==2){
                                changeLabel(arg2, item, p2, 2);
                            }
                            else if(newDate1.getDay()==3){
                                changeLabel(arg2, item, p3, 3);
                            }
                            else if(newDate1.getDay()==4){
                                changeLabel(arg2, item, p4, 4);
                            }
                            else if(newDate1.getDay()==5){
                                changeLabel(arg2, item, p5, 5);
                            }
                            else if(newDate1.getDay()==6){
                                changeLabel(arg2, item, p6, 6);
                            }
                            else{
                                changeLabel(arg2, item, p0, 7);
                            }
                            updateview();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            DBmanager(attendance(),newDate1);
                            //defaultview();
                            Log.d("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");

                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();               


                }
            });



            back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    newDate1.setDate(newDate1.getDate()-1);
                    update(newDate1);

                    if(updateViewUsingDB()==null){

                        defaultview();

                    }
                    else
                    {


                        switch (newDate1.getDay())
                        {
                        case 0:
                            p0=updateViewUsingDB();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            p1=updateViewUsingDB();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            p2=updateViewUsingDB();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            p3=updateViewUsingDB();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            p4=updateViewUsingDB(); 
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            p5=updateViewUsingDB();
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            p6=updateViewUsingDB();
                            break;
                        default:

                        }


                    }                  
                    updateview();
                    DBmanager(attendance(),newDate1);




                }
            }); 
            front.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    newDate1.setDate(newDate1.getDate()+1);
                    update(newDate1);

                    if(updateViewUsingDB()==null){

                        defaultview();

                    }
                    else
                    { 


                        switch (newDate1.getDay())
                        {
                        case 0:
                            p0=updateViewUsingDB();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            p1=updateViewUsingDB();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            p2=updateViewUsingDB();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            p3=updateViewUsingDB();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            p4=updateViewUsingDB();
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            p5=updateViewUsingDB();
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            p6=updateViewUsingDB();
                            break;
                        default:

                        }


                    }   
                    updateview();
                    DBmanager(attendance(),newDate1);



                }
            });




            Log.d("DBBBBBBPOSITION2JGH",""+position);


            DBmanager(attendance(),newDate1);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception


        Log.d("ERRRRRORRR","DONE");


    }


}


public void defaultview(){
    try{
        for(int i=0;i<ProjectBunkitActivity.pos;i++){
            p1[i]=sub[i];
            p2[i]=sub1[i];
            p3[i]=sub2[i];
            p4[i]=sub3[i];
            p5[i]=sub4[i];
            p6[i]=sub5[i];
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }




}

public String attendance(){

    String attn=null;
    try{
        switch (newDate1.getDay())
        {
        case 0:
            attn=stringConcat(p0);
            break;
        case 1:
            attn=stringConcat(p1);
            break;
        case 2:
            attn=stringConcat(p2);
            break;
        case 3:
            attn=stringConcat(p3);
            break;
        case 4:
            attn=stringConcat(p4);
            break;
        case 5:
            attn=stringConcat(p5);
            break;
        case 6:
            attn=stringConcat(p6);
            break;
        default:
            attn=stringConcat(p0);     
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return attn;


}


public void DBmanager(String attendance,Date theDate){



    try{
        Random rand=new Random();

        int i=newDate1.getDate(); 
        String s=setdate(newDate1.getDay());
        String mnth=setmon(newDate1.getMonth());
        long timevar=newDate1.getTime();

        int k;
        k=(100*newDate1.getDate())+newDate1.getMonth();
        SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("bunkDBNxTGeN", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
        cv.put("curId", position);
        cv.put("curPos",k);
        cv.put("curDay",s);
        cv.put("curDate",i);
        cv.put("curMnth",mnth);
        cv.put("curAttend",attendance);
        cv.put("curTime", timevar);

        position=rand.nextInt(10000-0)+0;


        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS theTable(curId INT(3),curPos INT(3),curTime INT(20),curDate INT(2),curDay VARCHAR,curMnth VARCHAR,curAttend VARCHAR);");

        db.insert("theTable",null, cv);


        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM theTable", null);
        c.moveToLast(); 
        Log.d("DB Message1", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("curId")));
        Log.d("DB Message1", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("curPos")));
        Log.d("DB Message2", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("curDate")));
        Log.d("DB Message3", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("curDay")));
        Log.d("DB Message4", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("curMnth")));
        Log.d("DB Message5", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("curAttend")));
        Log.d("DB Message6", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("curTime")));



        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE temp AS SELECT * FROM theTable ORDER BY curTime");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE theTable");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE temp RENAME TO theTable");
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM theTable WHERE curId NOT IN (SELECT curId FROM theTable GROUP BY curPos);");

        c.close();
        db.close();



    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.d("DB Message Error",e.toString());


    }



}
@SuppressWarnings("finally")
public String stringConcat(String [] arr){


    String str = "";
    try{
        for (int i = 0;i<arr.length; i++) {
            str = str+arr[i];
            if(i<arr.length-1){
                str = str+",";
            }
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    finally{

        return str;
    }


}


@SuppressWarnings("finally")
public String [] stringUncat(String str)
{
    String[] arr=null;
    try{

        arr= str.split(",");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    finally{
        return arr;
    }

}

public String[] updateViewUsingDB(){



    int curDate;
    curDate=(100*newDate1.getDate())+newDate1.getMonth();

    String s12=null;
    String s123[];
    int index,x;
    SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("bunkDBNxTGeN", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    try{
        if (db == null) {
            Log.d("Database", "Not Found!!!");
        } 
        else {


            Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM theTable", null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            index=c.getColumnIndex("curPos");
            x=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(index));
            while(index!=-1) 
            {
                if(x==curDate)
                {

                    s123=stringUncat(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("curAttend")));
                    db.close();
                    return s123;

                }
                else{

                    c.moveToNext();
                    index=c.getColumnIndex("curPos");
                    x=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(index));

                }
            }

            Log.d("DATABASE","UREAKAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"+s12);



        }
        db.close();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.d("DATABASE INFO",e.toString());
        db.close();

    }

    db.close();
    return null;





}


public void updateview()
{
    Log.d("DATEUPDATAVSCXZVAQAndlekdn", p1[0]);

    try{ 

        Log.d("DATEUPDAfSFSffdsFSDFAFkSDACDCSDndlekdn", p1[0]);


        if(setdate(newDate1.getDay())=="MON")
        {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.listarray, android.R.id.text1, p1);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else if(setdate(newDate1.getDay())=="TUE"){

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.listarray, android.R.id.text1, p2);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.d("DATEUPDATFwegfegewgRGSggekndlekdn", p1[0]);


        }
        else if(setdate(newDate1.getDay())=="WED"){

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.listarray, android.R.id.text1, p3);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        else if(setdate(newDate1.getDay())=="THU"){

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.listarray, android.R.id.text1, p4);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        else if(setdate(newDate1.getDay())=="FRI"){

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.listarray, android.R.id.text1, p5);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        else if(setdate(newDate1.getDay())=="SAT"){

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.listarray, android.R.id.text1, p6);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        else 
        {

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.listarray, android.R.id.text1, p0);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
        Log.d("DATEUPDAEFWEGFRHTkndlekdn", p1[0]);


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }


}


public void dateUpdate(){

    try{

        int m;
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date newDate = c.getTime();
        Log.d("DateXXX","heyyy");

        String s=setdate(newDate.getDay());
        String x=setmon(newDate.getMonth());

        Log.d("DATEEEEE",""+newDate.getDate());


        m=newDate.getDate();
        td.setText(s);
        tv.setText(x+","+m);
        updateview();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        Log.d("HEY THEREs An ERROR",e.toString());
    }

}
public void update(Date p)
{
    try{
        int m;

        String s=setdate(p.getDay());
        String x=setmon(p.getMonth());


        m=p.getDate();
        td.setText(s);
        tv.setText(x+","+m);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        Log.d("HEY THERE An ERROR",e.toString());
    }




}


private String setmon(int month) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String d=null;
    try{
        switch (month){

        case 0:d="JAN";
        break;
        case 1:d="FEB";
        break;
        case 2:d="MAR";
        break;
        case 3:d="APL";
        break;
        case 4:d="MAY";
        break;
        case 5:d="JUN";
        break;
        case 6:d="JULY";
        break;
        case 7:d="AUG";
        break;
        case 8:d="SEP";
        break;
        case 9:d="OCT";
        break;
        case 10:d="NOV";
        break;
        case 11:d="DEC";
        break;

        default:d="JAN";


        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return d;
}


private String setdate(int day) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String d=null;
    try{
        switch (day)
        {
        case 0:d="SUN";
        break;
        case 1:d="MON";
        break;
        case 2:d="TUE";
        break;
        case 3:d="WED";
        break;
        case 4:d="THU";
        break;
        case 5:d="FRI";
        break;
        case 6:d="SAT";
        break;
        default:d="MON1";
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return d;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    try{
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater(); //
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu); //
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return true; 
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        switch (item.getItemId()) { 
        case R.id.itemPrefs:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ProjectBunkitActivity.class)); 
            break;
        case R.id.itemPrefs1:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Display.class));
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public String[] changeLabel(int i,int j,String[] p,int l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //p6[arg2]=x[item];
    try{
        String storage[][]={
                sub,
                sub1,
                sub2,
                sub3,
                sub4,
                sub5,p01};

        //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Timetablledisplay.this,storage[l-1][i],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        //toast.show();
        switch (j) {
        case 0:

            p[i]=storage[l-1][i];

            break;
        case 1:p[i]="BNK";
        break;

        case 2:p[i]="FREE";
        break;

        default:
            break;
        }


        DBmanager(attendance(),newDate1);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return p;

}







@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();


    try{
        Calendar ca=Calendar.getInstance();
        ca.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
        Date dres=ca.getTime(); 
        newDate1=dres;

        Log.d("DATEUPDATE", "DONE");
        dateUpdate();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.d("DATEUPDATE", e.toString());

    }

}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        super.onPause();

        Log.d("DATqewDATE", "jhwedhjkebjd");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    //      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
    //      editor.putInt("position",position);     
}


@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("DATEUPDATE", "HGJVVM");

    try{
        p1=savedInstanceState.getStringArray("mond");
        p2=savedInstanceState.getStringArray("tued");
        p3=savedInstanceState.getStringArray("wedd");
        p4=savedInstanceState.getStringArray("thud");
        p5=savedInstanceState.getStringArray("frid");
        p6=savedInstanceState.getStringArray("satd");

        Calendar ca=Calendar.getInstance();
        ca.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
        Date dres=ca.getTime();
        newDate1=dres;

        Log.d("DATEUPDATE1212", "DONE");
        dateUpdate();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}



@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    try{
        savedInstanceState.putStringArray("mond", p1);
        savedInstanceState.putStringArray("tued", p2);
        savedInstanceState.putStringArray("wedd", p3);
        savedInstanceState.putStringArray("thud", p4);
        savedInstanceState.putStringArray("frid", p5);
        savedInstanceState.putStringArray("satd", p6);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



public void getSettings(){



    try{

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myfile",0); 
        restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null); 
        restoredText1 = prefs.getString("cpd", null);
        restoredText2= prefs.getString("nos", null);

        int pos1=prefs.getInt("pos",1);
        int l=0;

        if (restoredText != null) {

            Log.d("HHHHH", "Here"+pos1); 
            try{

                for(int j=0;j<=pos1-1;j++) 
                {
                    sw[l]=prefs.getString("sub"+l,null); 
                    Log.d("DATA FROM PREFS",sw[l]);
                    l++;

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Timetablledisplay.this,e.toString()+"5",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            } 
            getTimeTablesetting();


        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }




}




public void getTimeTablesetting(){



    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myTime",0);


    try{
        if(ProjectBunkitActivity.pos==prefs.getInt("pos",0)){ 
            if(prefs.getString("sub"+2, null) != null)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<prefs.getInt("pos",0);i++)
                {
                    sub[i] = prefs.getString("sub"+i, null); 
                    sub1[i] = prefs.getString("sub1"+i, null); 
                    sub2[i] = prefs.getString("sub2"+i, null); 
                    sub3[i] = prefs.getString("sub3"+i, null); 
                    sub4[i] = prefs.getString("sub4"+i, null); 
                    sub5[i] = prefs.getString("sub5"+i, null); 

                    Log.d("DATA FROM PREFS FOR TIME TABLE",sub[i]+i);

                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.d("DATA FROM PREFS FOR TIME TABLE","ERROR");

    }



}

}
```

This code takes some values from the preferences and converts it into a listview and its updates the date whenever the back or front button is pressed.what it also does is write data into db

Comment: you have `NullPointerException` at your `ArrayAdapter`. Check it.

Comment: the entire code is in a web of try-catches...I din leave out a single line

Comment: have you considered looking at the line which is producing the error...

Comment: Post some code if you want more help

Comment: I went through the code a lot of times...no null pointers

Comment: You posted a crash log that says "FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException" I'm gonna go on a limb here and say you have a null pointer somewhere..

Comment: check out the code...ive tried to handle all exceptions

Comment: I lost all reputation i had on this dumb problem....can anyone help???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be only two possible causes for that `NullPointerException`:

- You've given the wrong `id` for the `TextView` where the adapter should put the data.
  For example if you this constructor:

  `ArrayAdapter<...>(Context, R.layout.layout_file, R.id.textview, List data);`

Then `R.id.textview` is not an `id` of a `View` present in the `R.layout.layout_file`.

- You have a `null` value in the `List`/`array` that represents the data passed to the adapter

Do you have a `TextView` with the `id` `@android:id/text1` in the `R.layout.listarray` layout file? If not, that is the source of your problem.

**Edit:**
Looking at your code, the problem could be those `p1`, `p2` arrays. You declare them as being of size `40`, but do you fill all the positions in them? Do you have `40` values to put in those arrays? If not, then at some point you would have only `null` values and the adapter doesn't like that.

Print the values in them to the `logcat` and see if you have `null` values in those arrays. If you do, then that is most likely your problem.

Comment: I dont think its the problem with the view....I run it before and it worked...but this time i used data from prefs instead of data from intent.After I did that this problem started

Comment: @jaisonDavis Do you have a `TextView` with the id `@android:id/text1` in the `R.layout.listarray` file?